# Fraction of integrals involving a limit and a DE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, definite-integrals, fractions

> Find:
>
> $$\frac{\overline{\text{P}}_1}{\overline{\text{P}}_2}:=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\frac{1}{\text{n}}\int_0^\text{n}\text{f}_1\left(t\right)\cdot\text{y}_1\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t}{\displaystyle\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\frac{1}{\text{n}}\int_0^\text{n}\text{f}_2\left(t\right)\cdot\text{y}_2\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t}\tag1$$

The things we know:

1. $$\text{f}_1\left(t\right)=\text{a}_1\cdot\sin\left(\omega_1\cdot t+\varphi_1\right)\tag2$$
2. $$\text{f}_2\left(t\right)=\text{a}_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega_2\cdot t+\varphi_2\right)\tag3$$
3. For $\text{y}_1\left(t\right)$ we need to solve:
   $$\text{f}_1\left(t\right)=\text{R}\cdot\text{y}_1'\left(t\right)+\text{L}\cdot\text{y}_1''\left(t\right)+\frac{1}{\text{C}}\cdot\text{y}_1\left(t\right)\tag4$$
4. For $\text{y}_2\left(t\right)$ we need to solve:
   $$\text{f}_2\left(t\right)=\text{R}\cdot\text{y}_2'\left(t\right)+\text{L}\cdot\text{y}_2''\left(t\right)+\frac{1}{\text{C}}\cdot\text{y}_2\left(t\right)\tag5$$

> All the variables are real and positive.

---

**My work**:

The work I did was wrong, thanks to [@Fimpellizieri](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173410/fimpellizieri) so I deleted my work.

Comment: Note that there are several simplifications: (1) assume $a_2 = 1$, (2) assume (after a change of variables) that $\phi_2 = 0, \omega_2 = 1$. Then it should be possible to show that $\phi_2$ may also be assumed to vanish.

Comment: I should note that $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are missing initial values in order for them to be uniquely determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding homogenous ODE for $(4)$ is linear with constant coefficients and can be easily solved with classical tools.
With respect to a particular solution for $(4)$, this kind of ODE is fairly standard.
First, we write

$$f_1(t)=a_1\Big(\sin(\omega_1t)\cos(\varphi_1)+\cos(\omega_1t)\sin(\varphi_1)\Big).$$

Notice that $\cos(\varphi_1)$ and $\sin(\varphi_1)$ are constants.
Now, we guess

$$y_1(t)=a_1\Big(x\sin(\omega_1t)+z\cos(\omega_1t)\Big),$$

where $x$ and $z$ are to be determined.
Then

$$y_1'(t)=a_1\Big(x\omega_1\cos(\omega_1t)-z\omega_1\sin(\omega_1t)\Big)$$
$$y_1''(t)=a_1\Big(-x\omega_1^2\sin(\omega_1t)-z\omega_1^2\cos(\omega_1t)\Big)$$

Plugging everything into the ODE and cancelling out $a_1$, we find that

$$\sin(\omega_1t)\cos(\varphi_1)+\cos(\omega_1t)\sin(\varphi_1)=\\
\Big(-Rz\omega_1-Lx\omega_1^2+\frac1Cx\Big)\sin(\omega_1t)
+
\Big(-Rx\omega_1-Lz\omega_1^2+\frac1Cz\Big)\cos(\omega_1t)
$$

Therefore, a solution comes from the system

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\cos(\varphi_1)=\left(\frac1C-L\omega_1^2\right)x-\left(R\omega_1\right)z\\
\sin(\varphi_1)=\left(\frac1C-L\omega_1^2\right)z-\left(R\omega_1\right)x
\end{array}\right.$$

on the unknowns $x,z$.
One can similarly solve $y_2(t)$.

Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Solving the DE is not the problem, the problem is the limit!

Comment: Knowing the form of the solution to the DE, you should be able to calculate the integral. What kind of difficulty have you been facing here?